# Como obter todos os parâmetros numa requisição GET com Silex?

Tags: php, silex

Estou tendo os meus primeiros contatos com o framework Silex.

Tenho o seguinte script para poder capturar um parâmetro `GET`:

```
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Silex\Application $app) {

    return sprintf('Meu nome é %s', $request->query->get('nome'));
});
```

Ao usar `get` eu consigo capturar um parâmetro especifico da url. Mas como faço para pegar todos os parâmetros? Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Da uma olhada se isso ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455336/how-do-i-obtain-all-the-get-parameters-on-silex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar **`$request->request->all()`** que vai te retornar um array com todos os parâmetros.

---

#### Adicional

Fora a opção que você já conhece **`$request->query->get('nome')`**, você pode colocar os parâmetros da requisição como argumentos do método, desde que tenha o parâmetro definido na rota (`pattern: /{nome}`)

```
$app->get('/{nome}', function (Request $request, Silex\Application $app, $nome) {    
    return sprintf('Meu nome é %s', $nome);
});
```